# How to display view results by a value in a common field of page node

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a node page, and I have a view of nodes on this node page.  The main node and the node results share a taxonomy field.

I need to only display results that share the same values as the parent node.  I know I need to do this with contextual filters somehow, but I can't seem to get the filter set.

Comment: could you please try the solution described here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3

Comment: That works.  Can you post and answer so I may check it as answered?